# How to insert current time in sqlalchemy and python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# Define the MariaDB engine using MariaDB Connector/Python

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://root:1234@127.0.0.1:3306/project")

Base = declarative_base()

class Visitors(Base):
    __tablename__ = "visits"
    datetime=sqlalchemy.column(sqlalchemy.datetime)
    picture=sqlalchemy.column(sqlalchemy.String(length=200))
    name=sqlalchemy.column(sqlalchemy.String(length=50))
    
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
Session = Session()

newVisitor = Visitors(datetime=datetime, picture="example.jpg",name="chrome")
Session.add(newVisitor)
Session.commit()
```

**output**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/projectF/database.py", line 10, in 
> class Visitors(Base):
> File "c:/projectF/database.py", line 12, in Visitors
> datetime=sqlalchemy.column(sqlalchemy.datetime)
> AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: datetime= sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime)

Answer (score 0):

You defined the column type incorrectly, the `DateTime` type is found under `sqlalchemy.types`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime

class Visitors(Base):
    __tablename__ = "visits"
    datetime = sqlalchemy.column(DateTime)

newVisitor = Visitors(datetime=datetime.now(), picture="example.jpg", name="chrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import func

class Visitors(Base):
    __tablename__ = "visits"
    datetime = sqlalchemy.column(DateTime,server_default=func.now())
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?